# How to prevent GRUB from scanning lvm snapshot?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, snapshot, lvm2

My root file system is a LVM2 logic volume, and there are few snapshots of it beside.
Every time when I run update-grub, it always add menu entries for those snapshots as if they are normal volumes. This behavior not only generates garbage in grub.cfg, but also let it possible to hurt my system because booting from a snapshot is defective.

I know `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` can solve it, but I still need OS prober also, because there are Windows volumes in same disk, and I want grub making menu entries for them.

Is there a way I can do it ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Best way is to write a simple and clean grub.cfg yourself and avoid using `grub-mkconfig` or any wrapper of it  (`update-grub` whatsoever) once and for all.

Comment: Chainloading Windows is a one-liner. `linux` and `intrid` take two. Usually the only other command one might need for an entry is `search -s`. The story essentially ends with a single `insmod` and perhaps `timeout` in addition. Though it is a bit of a hassle for versioned kernel.